# ngFor converts string literal type to string, throws "Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used...."

Tags: angular, typescript, templates, ngfor, string-literals

Using the iterator `*ngFor` converts a string union literal type `("apple" | "banana")` to a string type. When I use it as an index of an array expecting the correct string union literal type I get the error:

> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'FruitCollection'.

`apple-banana-component.ts`:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

const Fruits = ["apple", "banana"] as const;
type Fruit = typeof Fruits[number]; // "apple" | "banana"
type FruitCollection = { [fruit in Fruit]: number }; // {apple: number, banana: number}

@Component({
    selector: 'app-apple-banana',
    templateUrl: './apple-banana.component.html'
})
export class AppleBananaComponent implements OnInit {
    fruitBasket: FruitCollection = {
        apple: 10,
        banana: 10
    }
    fruitEaten: FruitCollection = {
        apple: 0,
        banana: 0
    }
    constructor() { }
    ngOnInit(): void { }
    eatFruit(fruit: Fruit) {
        this.fruitEaten[fruit]++;
        this.fruitBasket[fruit]--;
    }
}
```

`apple-banana-component.html`:

```
<div>
You have eaten {{fruitEaten['apple']}} apples and {{fruitEaten['banana']}} bananas. <!-- works -->

<div *ngFor="let fruit of fruitBasket | keyvalue">
    {{fruit.key}}: 
    {{fruit.value}} in basket, 
    {{fruitEaten[fruit.key]}}  <!-- ERROR: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'FruitCollection'. -->    
    eaten.
    <button (click)="eatFruit($any(fruit.key))">eat {{fruit.key}}</button>
</div>
</div>
```

For some reason I can't comprehend, `$any(fruit.key)` works inside `eatFruit()` but not inside `fruitBasket[]`.

```
{{fruitEaten[fruit.key as Fruit]}} <!-- ERROR: Parser Error: Missing expected ] at column 22 [...] -->

{{fruitEaten[fruit.key as keyof typeof fruitEaten]}} <!-- ERROR: Parser Error: Missing expected ] at column 22 [...] -->

{{fruitEaten[$any(fruit.key)]}} <!-- ERROR: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'any' can't be used to index type 'FruitCollection'. -->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the `key` produced by the `keyvalue` is always a `string`. You can't use a `string` to index your type but you also can't use type assertions in a template. The `$any` was a good idea, but even `any` is not allowed to index object types without index signatures when `noImplicitAny` is set to `true`.

You could create a function in your component to do the *casting*.

`apple-banana-component.ts`

```
public isFruit(value: string): Fruit {
  return value as Fruit
}
```

You can now use this function in your template.

```
<div *ngFor="let fruit of fruitBasket | keyvalue">
    {{fruit.key}}: 
    {{fruit.value}} in basket, 
    {{fruitEaten[isFruit(fruit.key)]}}
    eaten.
    <button (click)="eatFruit(isFruit(fruit.key))">eat {{fruit.key}}</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, it works so I accepted your answer, but there is an alternative solution I just found that I will be using instead: If you iterate over `Fruits`, the string literal union type is preserved and can be used to index arrays and as argument of functions. See my self-answer.

Answer (score 2):

Self-answering because I have just found a solution that works for me. The workaround by Tobias S. works, but it requires defining a new function. One can instead iterate over the constant Fruits:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

const Fruits = ["apple", "banana"] as const;
type Fruit = typeof Fruits[number]; // "apple" | "banana"
type FruitCollection = { [fruit in Fruit]: number }; // {apple: number, banana: number}

@Component({
    selector: 'app-apple-banana',
    templateUrl: './apple-banana.component.html'
})
export class AppleBananaComponent implements OnInit {
    fruits = Fruits;
    fruitBasket: FruitCollection = {
        apple: 10,
        banana: 10
    }
    fruitEaten: FruitCollection = {
        apple: 0,
        banana: 0
    }
    constructor() { }
    ngOnInit(): void { }
    eatFruit(fruit: Fruit) {
        this.fruitEaten[fruit]++;
        this.fruitBasket[fruit]--;
    }
}
```

I don't understand why, but iterating over `fruits of Fruits = ["apple", "banana"]` instead of over `fruitBasket[]` preserves the string literal union type inside `*ngFor`, preventing any type errors.

```
<div *ngFor="let fruit of Fruits">
    {{fruit}}: 
    {{fruitBasket[fruit]}} in basket,
    {{fruitEaten[fruit]}} eaten.
    eaten.
    <button (click)="eatFruit(fruit)">eat {{fruit}}</button>
</div>
```

So I am not sure why this works, but it does.

Comment: yeah that works too I guess :)